# How to correctly instantiating data model from JSON in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, struct, swift2, models

I'm looking for a clean and correct way to instantiate data models in swift.

I've been searching for a while and I haven't found a definitive answer yet. I found a lot of simple examples for teaching purpose (like the one proposed by Apple itself [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson6.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH20-SW1)) but not a real life case. I mean: how  to instantiate a data model from a complex JSON returned by an API, while managing optionals and failable initialization elegantly?

I'm interested in a pure swift style, so please don't answer with obj-c solutions or suggesting libraries to easily handle JSONS in swift because this is not the real point of my question. There are third party libraries for everything (and I use them too), but what I'm looking for here is to learn in depth swift syntax and gain awareness about its inner patterns.

Below I propose several solutions that I adopted until now. Really interested in your advices, arguments and explications.

EDIT:
Some aspects I'm particularly concerned:

1) Given that a model's property can be set as `nil`, which is the best property declaration? As Optionals? As unwrapped Optional?

2) Which assignation pattern works best? `if let` bindings or `guard` bindings?

3) How to handle correctly the instantiation of a model that is a property of an my actual model? (consider `var myObjects` in the snipped below)

For each question above I've already found my answer, but I'm interested in other points of view because I think Swift is a very rich and malleable language and Apple official documentation sometimes lacks in clarity about best practices.

```
//Proposition 2: property as Optionals and use of guard let

struct MyModel {

    let a: String?
    let b: MyOtherModel? // MyOtherModel is another struct similar to this one
    var myObjects = [Object]()  // Object is another struct similar to this one

    init?(data: AnyObject) {

      guard let data = data as? JSON,
            let a = json["a"] as? String,
            let otherData = json["b"] as AnyObject,
            let myObjectsArray = json["objects"] as? [AnyObject] else {
        return nil
      }
      self.a = a
      self.b = MyOtherModel(otherData)

      for data in myObjectsArray {
        if let newObject = Object(data) {
          self.myObjects.append(newObject)
        }
      }
    } 

}


//Proposition 2: properties as unwrapped Optionals and if let bindings

struct MyModel {

    let a: String!
    let b: MyOtherModel! // MyOtherModel is another struct similar to this one
    var myObjects = [Object]()  // Object is another struct similar to this one

    init?(data: AnyObject) {

      if let data = data as? JSON,
         let a = json["a"] as? String,
         let otherData = json["b"] as AnyObject,
         let myObjectsArray = json["objects"] as? [AnyObject] {

        self.a = a
        self.b = MyOtherModel(otherData)
        for data in myObjectsArray {
          if let newObject = Object(data) {
            self.myObjects.append(newObject)
          }
        }
      }
      else {
        return nil
      }
    } 

}

//Proposition 3: properties already initialized, forcing unwrapping of json sub-objects

struct MyModel {

    let a = String()
    let b = MyOtherModel() // MyOtherModel is another struct similar to this one
    var myObjects = [Object]()  // Object is another struct similar to this one

    init?(data: AnyObject) {

        self.a = data["a"]
        self.b = MyOtherModel(data["b"]!!)

        if let myObjectsArray = data["b"] as [AnyObject] {
          for data in myObjectsArray {
            if let newObject = Object(data) {
              self.myObjects.append(newObject)
            }
          }
        }
        if (self.a.isEmpty) {
          return nil
        }
      }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Proposition 1 is the best, because of the guard statement and the failable initializer. So, what do you expect more?

Comment: What is against using a Swift JSON library? It makes the code much more readable and concise

Comment: @Darko I edited. For Kametrixom: I'm not against JSON libraries (I use them everyday). Here I pose the emphasis on a pure Swift style because I want to understand Swift till the end to improve my skills.

Comment: I wish this question had gotten more attention. This is the exact question I was asking myself now when moving from Objective-C to Swift

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any 'elegant' way of handling JSON. In terms of readable code I have generally took this approach, not saying it's the only way:

Model:

```
class Category : NSObject {

    // Model Objects
    var categoryId: NSNumber!
    var categoryDesc: String!
    var inAppId: String!
    var categoryUnlocked: NSNumber!

    override init() {
        self.categoryId         = 0
        self.categoryDesc       = ""
        self.inAppId            = ""
        self.categoryUnlocked   = 0
    }

    convenience init(categoryDictionary: [String : AnyObject]) {
        self.init()

        self.categoryId         = NSNumber(int: categoryDictionary["CategoryID"]!.intValue)
        self.categoryDesc       = categoryDictionary["Category_Desc"] as? String ?? ""
        self.inAppId            = categoryDictionary["InAppID"] as? String ?? ""
        self.categoryUnlocked   = categoryDictionary["CategoryUnlocked"] as? NSNumber ?? 0
    }

}
```

With the JSON I use the array.map function:

```
var categoryList = [Category]()
if let catArray = data["categories"] as? NSArray {
      categoryList = catArray.map({Category(categoryDictionary: $0 as! [String : AnyObject])})
      CoreDataService.instance.saveCategories(categoryList)
}
```

This way is tidy and readable for future developers and easily manageable within the specific Model.